# extract addresses from google map

Tags: php, javascript

how can i extract all addresses,corresponding latitude & longitude of a city(eg:Bangalore) from google map using php/js and store in mysql table .can anyone help me.Its urgent.Thank Yo

Comment: -1 for apparent data scraping attempt and especially "its urgent".

Answer (score 4):

Have a read through the [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/).

> The Google Places API is a service
>   that returns information about a
>   "place" (hereafter referred to as a
>   Place) — defined within this API as an
>   establishment, a geographic location,
>   or prominent point of interest — using
>   an HTTP request. Place requests
>   specify locations as
>   latitude/longitude coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

You should also read the terms:

> **License Restrictions**
>
> 10.3 pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store
>   limited amounts of Content for the
>   purpose of improving the performance
>   of your Maps API Implementation if you
>   do so temporarily, securely, and in a
>   manner that does not permit use of the
>   Content outside of the Service;